# Careers Notification for a message keeps getting resent

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I'm not sure wether or not this is the right place to post this, but I've clicked on the *feedback is welcomed* link on the Careers Stackoverflow site and arrived here.

I have a Careers profile which I don't really use. I got messaged by someone (a company) about a position, I chose to ignore the message (don't want to reply). I've read the message on the website, and it has been marked as read.

Following that, I get a notification weekly or once every two weeks titled:
*Reminder: X is waiting to hear from you - Stack Overflow Careers 2.0*.

I've checked several times, and even went out of my way to select the message and click the *mark as read* button, but the emails still come.

This must be a bug.

Comment: That message is coming from Careers or from the company?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting notifications is because you chose to ignore the message.  On Careers we expect you to respond to employer emails, even if you are not interested.  Simply marking the message as read will not prevent you from receiving these reminders, only responding to the message will.  If you want to ignore it, my best suggestion is that you respond not interested with an empty text response.  After 14 days of not responding to a message we will automatically mark your account not searchable.

Comment: *looks up and runs and replies to message*. Is it stated somewhere obvious that this is the behavior? I wasn't aware that it was, and obviously this guy wasn't either. Though for some reason I wasn't getting bugged by that `x is waiting` message.

Comment: @ryan agreed.  You should propose this as a feature request in a separate meta thread, asking the UI have more clarity.

Comment: @djechlin done http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176815/clarify-carreers-2-0-functionality-to-make-it-clear-that-messages-need-to-be-res

Comment: `After 14 days of not responding to a message we will automatically mark your account not searchable` That's a scary feature; is that toggelable by the user (same as the employer view setting?) or something you can't fix?

Comment: @BenBrocka it is the searchable setting on the privacy tab and yes you can come back and set it anytime.

Comment: that cetainly looks like the behaviour i've been seeing, but doesn't that seem all kinds of weird and broken?