# Allow me to unsubscribe from Careers 2.0 emails.

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I have been receiving the message below every 7 days from the same person. It's very annoying.

> `<User>` viewed your profile on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 and sent
>   you a message on Jun 3.
>
> Click here to view your message
>
> To reply, click on the link above. Writing a response is optional: if
>   you want, you can just indicate "Interested" or "Not Interested".
>
> You are currently shown as passively looking for a job. If this is no
>   longer correct, please update your job search status.
>
> If the above link is not clickable, copy and paste this link into your
>   web browser's address bar:

Could an option to unsubscribe from such messages be added?

Answer (score 2):

related to [NickLarsen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184424/225389) post:

I use Careers 2.0 only as public profile of my Developer skills (little bid narcissistic, but that's how it is). Even if it provides communication feature (messages) it's up to me as a user decide if I will use that feature. I think is really bad idea to remind user over and over "you still didn't reply" => therefore force them to reply

If I wanted to answer that message I would do that from the Careers 2.0 interface in the first place. But that's not the issue. The issue is that I cannon un-susscribe from notification feed.

so just a suggestion:

From UX perspective: respecting users choice to unsuscribe from a certain email feed is not a new feature, it's a key feature in any social web-application (yes even if we talking about email feed notifying user that he has a message)

More important, from marketing perspective: If user has no capability to unsuscribe or turn off notifications he will usually send **these kind of emails to spam**. This devalueate whole domain in eyes of span filters.

Facebook, LindkedIn, LoveThis and basically all social networking applications accept this basic UX principle ...I really think that people behind Careers2.0 should rethink this.

And one more comment for future to consider: So far the idea behind Careers2.0 was really nice (Despite ignoring user right to unsusscribe from emails :) ), please don't try to  turn it into LinkedIn alike application

P.S. sorry comment was to small to fit this in

Comment: you should edit this material into your question. It's not an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can reply `not interested` to this employer through the interface on the link included in this email and it will effectively kill the thread.  We will **not** allow you to turn off this specific email because it is the primary way of getting in touch with you once someone has attempted to contact you through our site.  If you really just don't like this person, there is an option to block all further contact with them when you are replying not interested.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with this: it's not like LinkedIn or Facebook. It's not a social network. It's a job listing service. You're not there to 'connect' with friends; its primary purpose is to connect you with companies looking for your skills.

If you want to 'unsubscribe' from getting emails, check the box that says you won't accept any communication from potential employers. Otherwise you have explicitly opted in to being contacted by potential employers.

Remember it's a 2 way street. Those companies using the feature have paid to use the feature and as part of that payment, they have been guaranteed that any communication they send will be effective! And they have also been promised that anyone who can be found and contacted (meaning they haven't checked the box I mentioned above), ***must reply*** or they will be removed from search lists.

See [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176815/clarify-careers-2-0-functionality-to-make-it-clear-that-messages-need-to-be-resp) for more information on SE's terms of service with companies. As to them being classified as spam: please don't do that. Companies are *limited* on the number of emails they can send out at a time, so they can't in-fact spam you.

Comment: I agree the app is not a Social network, I see now that I mentioned bad example. App doesn't have to be social network, any decent e-commerce solution (unsubscribe from certain mailing-list) any decent community forum (stop reciving notifications).   But the fact stays that app is suspecting that users will behave certain way (in this cas they wont put these kind of stuff to spam, well they will). Never going to happen. Trying to bend the user towards the application will backfire. For many users any annoying email will end in spam

Comment: @equivalent8 That doesn't change the ToS of the Careers app. It also doesn't change the fact that you *do* have a way to unsubscribe. You can make it so that no one can notify you, but *if* you are going to use the app at all then you agree to the ToS which says that you **must** respond to those emails, and you will be notified until you do. If you choose to put them in spam, that's your prerogative but the app will change your status automatically to, **do not contact,** so that future companies don't waste time contacting you.